# MVC Razor View - nested foreach displays the correct info but on a different line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

In View have the following foreach loop to display links:

```
@model List<IGrouping<string, FileInfo>>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    int i = 0;
}

<div class="container-fluid main-container">
  <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

        @foreach (var link in @Model)
        {
            <li><a href="#">@link.Key</a> <span>(***)</span></li> 

            foreach(var item in Model[i])
            {
                @item.Culture;
            }

            i++;
         }
      </ul>
   </div>
```

The nested foreach displays the correct info but on a different line - I would like it positioned where the `***` is in code listing.

Also I would like a comma ',' placed between each culture.

Any help appreciated.

Current output showing as:

[image]

**EDIT**: updated code to following and still getting same issue

```
 @foreach (var link in @Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="#">@link.Key</a> 
                <span>
                    @foreach(var item in link)
                    {
                        @item.Culture
                    }
                </span>
            </li>
        }
```

Comment: what is `i` here?

Comment: I think your `<li>` is closed too early. Close it after the second `foreach`

Comment: @PaoloB `IGrouping` inherts from `IEnumerable`, which means you can loop through `link`. `foreach(var item in link)
            {
                @item.Culture;
            }`. You don't need the `i`

Comment: @PaoloB have you tried ovation22's answer?

Comment: yes, please see below

Comment: @PaoloB try the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this? (untested)

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
  <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

        @foreach (var link in @Model)
        {
            <li><a href="#">@link.Key</a> <span>

            @String.Join(", ", link.Select(item => item.Culture).ToArray())

            </span></li> 
         }
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: shows 'de, fr, nl, i++;' on new line - if change to `@i++;` then I get 'de, fr, nl, 0++;' on new line?

Comment: Yes I see, needed to be in the <a> tag also but working now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this ?

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
  <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

    @foreach (var link in @Model)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@link.Key</a> <span> 

        foreach(var item in Model[i])
        {
            @item.Culture; 
            @:,
        }
        </span></li>
        i++;
     }
  </ul>
```

Comment: Try this edit, if it dosen't work i don't know, sorry.

Comment: I just copied your solution and changed the html tags. It should work like before. But im not 100% sure what you mean with your question tho. Give an example of the output please.

Answer (score 0):

With the power of razor something like this should work.

Edit: just realised you want all cultures so:

```
        @foreach (var link in @Model)
        {
            var Culture = "";
            @foreach( var item in Model[i])
            {
                Culture += string.format("{0}," @item.culture;)
            }
            <li><a href="#">@link.Key</a> <span>(@Culture.trimend(','))</span></li>    
            i++;
         }
```

Comment: This won't work. `Model[i]` is of type `IGrouping<string, FileInfo>`. It doesn't have a property called `item`

Comment: yes item would need to be replaced with whatever your hoping to get culture from.

Comment: `Model[i]` is of type `IGrouping<string, FileInfo>`. It has only one property and it's `Key`, pointing to an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`